# Getting rid of unnecessary join when using link tables with EF

Tags: entity-framework, orm, linq-to-entities, linktable

I have this database schema:

```
User  <--  UserRole  -->  Role
```

The Role table has a few columns but I'm only interested in the primary key and I can get that from UserRole's foreign key so I wouldn't really need to join in the Role table at all, but I can't figure out how to avoid joining to that table with EF.

I tried this code:

```
context.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == x).Single().Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
```

This generates two queries. One on the user table and one on a join of UserRole and Role. I can of course reduce it to one query by using .Include("Roles") or SelectMany() but that query would join three tables. Is there a way to get rid of the superfluous join? I want my SQL to resemble this:

```
SELECT u.*, ur.RoleId
FROM User u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE ...
```

In reality I'm using automapper, but I think this example demonstrates the same problem. Roles is a small table so I can live with the performance penalty this time, but it bugs me that I can't get it as efficient as handwritten SQL. Has anyone else run into this before me and figured out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (I don't use `var` here to make the types explicit):

```
IQueryable<IEnumerable<int>> query = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == x)
    .Select(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId));

IEnumerable<int> result = query.Single();
```

This

- throws an exception if the user with `UserId == x` doesn't exist. (I guess you want that because you are using `Single` in your example.)
- returns a collection of `RoleId`s of user `x`. The collection can be empty (`result.Count() == 0`) if the user isn't in any role.
- creates the following SQL for `query` (with `x == 1`) which only joins `User` and `UserRoles` table:

  ```
  SELECT 
  [Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
  [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
  [Project1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
  FROM ( SELECT 
          [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
          [Extent2].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
         CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[UserId] IS NULL) 
             THEN CAST(NULL AS int) 
             ELSE 1
         END AS [C1]
         FROM  [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
         LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserRoles] AS [Extent2]
             ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]
         WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[UserId]
       )  AS [Project1]
  ORDER BY [Project1].[UserId] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
  ```

If you don't want to distinguish if the user doesn't exist or exists but has no roles you can get a much simpler SQL with this query:

```
IQueryable<int> query = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == x)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId));

IEnumerable<int> result = query.ToList();
```

This returns an empty collection if the user has no roles **or** if the user doesn't exist. But the SQL is very simple:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
FROM [dbo].[UserRoles] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[UserId]
```

So, here is no join between tables involved at all and the query only uses the `UserRoles` link table.

Answer (score 0):

I use roles more efficiently.

Checkout [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) for adding roles to your usertables.

What flags does:

Creates a sort of Enum with:

```
Administrator = 1
Moderator = 2
SuperUser = 4
User = 8
Visitor = 16
```

You add an attribute Role in the Usertable as Integer.

```
"User" = Administrator + Moderator --> Role =  3 ( 1 + 2 )
"User" = Moderator + SuperUser     --> Role =  6 ( 2 + 4 )
"User" = SuperUser + User          --> Role = 12 ( 4 + 8 )
```

No Junction table anymore and solves your issue.

(Though additional coding will be required for adding the logic into your application)

Comment: Yes, I can sacrifice normalization for speed, but I'm curious if I can solve this without altering the database schema.